# I can't get result at sparql tab

Tags: sparql, protege

[this is tutorial that i have follow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7a-WQQiJaYs)

I have followed some basic protege tutorials ... and I never got the results from the sparql ...

When I execute the results are always empty. even though I have followed the tutorial exactly.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX ex: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rosel/ontologies/2019/2/nyoba#>
SELECT ?subject ?object
    WHERE { ex:tania ex:enroll ?object }
```

Comment: ... because the query does **not** match the data I'd **guess** - and I said "guess" because you didn't show the data ... check your ontology either in a text editor or the Protege RDF/XML view. Are the prefix declarations correct? And then check whether there is an individual `ex:tanja` with such a property.

Comment: Also very "good" that you didn't share the tutorial with us ...

Comment: @AKSW iI'm sorry I didn't include the tutorial. I'm new at this. I have edited my question by adding a screenshot of my protege and a link from the tutorial ...

Comment: but the screenshot can't be displayed because my reputation is less than 10

Comment: please do `select * where {?s ?p ?o}` to check if there is any data at all.